# How is the aggregation achieved with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

How is the aggregation achieved with MongoDB ?

using mongoDB for some near real time aggregation and how it scale if the aggregation pipeline results are large ?

Is there any performance tuning methods during aggregation

Comment: This is 3 questions and each of them is too broad to be answered with anything less than a multi-page essay.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any performance tuning methods during aggregation

There are many. You should refer [the documentation about query optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/)

> using mongoDB for some near real time aggregation and how it scale if the aggregation pipeline results are large ?

[Refer this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#limit-the-number-of-query-results-to-reduce-network-demand)

1. Limit the number of documents - to handle network demand
2. use projection to return only the necessary fields.

Comment: thanks for the link.. any links on how scaling can happen during aggregation ?

Comment: 1. Mongo will slow down when aggregation results in huge number of documents, let's say you are trying to group 5million docs and return 3 million. `It will slow down due to network demand`. 2. Think twice before retuning huge documents. you can use paginated results. 3. To make the aggregation faster, you should look at the query optimisation, pipeline optimisation. Mostly it depends on design, query, network, resources you have in your cluster. MongoDB documentation suggests us to try multiple design approaches to identify the best suited for a use case.